# SQL Server Reports Builder - showing dates of current week (help)

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2016, sqlreportingservice

I am using SQL Server Report Builder to generate a weekly report to show the weekdays Monday - Friday and then the relevant dates.

The report pulls the information from a calendar in SharePoint 2016.

Instead I have created 5 columns with static weekdays and the week dates:

The following generates the weekdays:

```
=IIf(UCase(Format(Fields!Start_Time.Value, "dddd"))="MONDAY",FORMAT(Fields!Start_Time.Value, "h:mm tt ") & FORMAT(Fields!End_Time.Value, "- h:mmtt"),"")
```

The following generates the week dates:

```
=FORMAT(Today.addDays(1-weekday(Today,FirstdayOfWeek.Monday)),"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

[Screenshot of the SQL Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecflj.jpg)

Which means show the date/time of each weekDay otherwise leave blank.
The problem with this approach is that does show all the entries even those of last week ...

The purpose is to show only for current week.
Unfortunately, I am out of ideas and not sure what else can be done?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

I have managed to find a way around this :) 
The expression needed to be:

```
=IIf(FORMAT(Fields!Start_Time.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy")=FORMAT(Today.addDays(1-weekday(Today,FirstdayOfWeek.Monday)),"dd/MM/yyyy"),FORMAT(Fields!Start_Time.Value, "h:mmtt ") & FORMAT(Fields!End_Time.Value, "- h:mmtt"),"")
```